# XAMPP: how to change max_user_connections on local mysql server

Tags: mysql

On XAMPP, in the GLOBAL_VARIABLES table the `max_user_connections` variable is 0.

After editing the `I:\xampp\mysql\bin\my.ini` file and adding this line at the bottom:

```
max_user_connections = 10
```

and rebooting mysql service, the max_user_connections is still 0. Another try was with different syntax I found on forums:

```
set-variable = max_user_connections=10
```

but it's still 0 in the GLOBAL_VARIABLES table.

So, how to change this variable?

P.S. I changed in `I:\xampp\mysql\bin\my.ini` file because I think this file is used by mysql. I tried to find the correct file using mysql --help but the locations included in its output didn't exist at all. 
These locations were:

```
C:\Windows\my.ini 
C:\Windows\my.cnf 
C:\my.ini 
C:\my.cnf 
I:\xampp\mysql\my.ini
```

The last folder exists, but it doesn't contain files my.ini or my.cnf.

Comment: Have you checked those locations listed in the output aren't hidden files/folders? P.s I think this should be on Superuser possibly

Comment: I updated the question with more details at the bottom. And all my folders are visible (I have 'show hidden folders' setting in Explorer).

Comment: Also try adding this line to your my.ini file: `max_connections = 10`.

Comment: It seems to have no effect. In GLOBAL_VARIABLES table the max_connections is 100, same as before. Either I am changing the wrong file or maybe the checking method is incorrect. The database is information_schema at localhost. In php you can type phpinfo() and it displays exactly which php.ini file it uses. Isn't there similar thing in mysql?

Comment: This is the right file. I found it out by checking the properties of the mysql process in task manager and viewing the executable path. It's `i:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe --defaults-file=i:\xampp\mysql\bin\my.ini mysql`. I also entered the mysql console and from there checked the variables using `show variables like 'max%';` and they are the same as previously stated. So, what's left? Maybe these variable settings should be under specific `[group]` in the my.ini file? (tried under `[mysqld]`, `[mysql]` and `[mysqld_safe]` with no success).

Comment: Oh well, success with `max_user_connections`. Putting it under `[mysqld]` group did the job. However, putting the `max_connections` under this group didn't work. Maybe it should be under another group. But I needed the `max_user_connections` only, so, I think it's solved, by trial and error.

Comment: I would have suggested putting the connections line under the `[client]` group in the settings file, but I'm glad that it's working for you. (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/option-files.html)